# Java File.createTempFile() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This Java 1.8.0_102 program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File tempFile = null;

        try {
            tempFile = File.createTempFile(null,  null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

According to the Javadocs, both arguments may be null.  Any idea why this particular exception is being thrown?

Comment: "*According to the Javadocs, both arguments may be null*" can you quote that fragment of documentation? From what I see [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) "The **prefix** string to be used in generating the file's name; **must be at least three characters long**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Yup.  See my comment below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix cannot be null according to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> Parameters:
>
> prefix - The prefix string to be used in generating the file's name; must be at least three characters long
>
> suffix - The suffix string to be used in generating the file's name; may be null, in which case the suffix ".tmp" will be used

Comment: I was reading the Javadocs for 1.8.0_20, not for 1.8.0_102 and they are **different**!  I know not to use the Javadocs for one version of Java while I'm compiling using a different version, but I've never had this issue come up for different releases of the *same* version.

Comment: @mbmast Java does not change the contract of a public method from one version to the next;  that would violate a fundamental principle of object-oriented design.  I suspect you have confused [File.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) (in java.io) with [Files.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) (in java.nio.file).

Comment: Ugh.  You are correct.  Does SO award badges for shame?

Answer (score 1):

The java doc says "prefix The prefix string to be used in generating the file's name; must be at least three characters long". Precisely why it is throwing null pointer exception. Here is the link [File java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

According to the error output, the exception is NullPointerException. However, according to the Javadocs for [File.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), that is not a thrown exception. That means something unexpected is going on with your code. We can see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/File.java#File.createTempFile%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.io.File%29) to see exactly what's going on (keep in mind the third parameter, `directory` is null because you used the overloaded version).

The very first thing it does is check to see the length of `prefix` and make sure that it's not less than 3 (on line 2000). However, since your value for `prefix` is `null`, checking `length()` on it will always return a NullPointerException because you can't call any methods on a null object. The fact that it didn't even get to throw the InvalidArgumentException is further evidence that it died in the if-check. We also can see both in the Javadoc and the source code that it requires `prefix` to be a String with 3 characters. Interestingly, in Java 6, this method *did* throw a NullPointerException explicitly if `prefix` was null.